# All currently opened window objects in java script

Tags: javascript

I need to get all window objects that are currently opened.
Is there way to do this in java script.

I tried using `window.open()`. But it either opened a new window or got access to existing window if I pass the window name.

Is it possible to apply `regex` in window name in `window.open()`

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend assigning variables to each of your popups:

```
var window1 = window.open('');
var window2 = window.open('');
var window3 = window.open('');
```

The `window` object should have all of the information that you need. Use this function to see what the `window` object contains:

```
//displays object properties in an array
var getKeys = function(obj) {
  var keys = [];
  for(var key in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  keys.push(key);
}
  }
  return keys;
}
```

In this case, simply call `console.log(getKeys(window))` and it will display what properties the object contains.

Comment: Lets say the variable losses the window object reference due to page reload by some means then i can't get the reference back.

Comment: Assign it to a cookie. Here's a cookie handler I wrote a little while back: http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_cookie_handler-JE9